# SSRS-WCF Communicaton

Tags: wcf, post, soap, reporting-services, get

I am facing a problem:

when sending soap query from ssrs to wcf , i am getting :

> `The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.`
>   `he HTTP verb POST used to access path '/Service1' is not allowed.`

sending soap messages from ssrs to wcf was working perfect but suddenly it breaks.i didnt changed anything in the code.code below.

**soap query very simple:**

```
<Query> <Method Name="GetData" Namespace="http://tempuri.org/"  /> <SoapAction>http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetData</SoapAction> <ElementPath IgnoreNamespaces="true">*</ElementPath> </Query>
```

contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {

        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);



        // TODO: Add your service operations here
    }



implementation:

 public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string GetData(int value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
        }


    }
```

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> <configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />   </system.web>   <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />   </system.serviceModel>  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

  </system.webServer>



     </configuration>
```

**for the web.config:**

this is the new web.config when you create wcfapplication it does not require you to include all the stuff and it will generate internally a web.config which you can see in the wcf test client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:58539/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="IService1"
                name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel> </configuration>
```

Comment: Can you post the rest of your service config - there is no endpoint or binding or anything.

Comment: @Mike Goodwin: posted thanks